# What is the proper way to move a vector (or anything else) from outside to a class member?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

`struct Something { ... };`

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<Something>&& vec)
    {
        myVec = vec;
    }
private:
    std::vector<Something> myVec;
};

void main()
{
    ...
    MyClass instance(std::move(someVector));
}
```

or

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<Something> vec)
    {
        myVec = std::move(vec);
    }
private:
    std::vector<Something> myVec;
};

void main()
{
    ...
    MyClass instance(someVector);
}
```

are they both wrong? The second one sure looks like it. Should I also worry about setting "vec" to some "valid data" after moving?
I'm sorry I'm new to both C++ and move semantics, thank you for your time :)

Comment: `MyClass(std::vector<Something>&& vec) { myVec = std::move(vec); }`. All your examples involve a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are wrong. The first one makes a copy (at `myVec = vec;`), and so does the second one (at `std::vector<Something> vec`).

You should also construct `MyClass` with an rvalue reference: `MyClass instance(std::move(someVector))`.

Here's how it should be done:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(std::vector<Something>&& vec) : myVec(std::move(vec))
    {
    }
private:
    std::vector<Something> myVec;
};

void main()
{
    ...
    MyClass instance(std::move(someVector));
}
```

The part `: myVec(std::move(vec))` is called a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It is more efficient that re-assigning members in the body of the constructor.